# How to get several single pdf pages in a single mPDF document?

Tags: php, mpdf

I´m running a pg query which returns a lot of records that i use to create individual 'Response Sheets'.  But i want these individual Sheets as a unique pdf Document, because i'll need to print these Sheets, so is easier to print one big single Mpdf Document that a lot of small single pdfs Sheets.  i didn't find anywhere how to do this, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4):

This will make a 2 page PDF

```
<?php

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Your Introduction');
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Your Book text');

?>
```